# Need help correcting & combining two functions into one

Tags: javascript

The Question is

Create a function called divisibles() that will take each object in upper and find all
    objects in lower that evenly divide into it, ignoring zero. The function should return an
    object that is upper but each object has an additional key called found and the value
    for that key is an array containing each item from lower that was evenly divided into it.
    Output the result of the function to the console.

Here's my code so far, I know I'm doing something very wrong and can't figure it out. I have it in two functions, can't figure out how to make it one, and my output doesn't look correct either.

```
 function divisibles(number, myArrayLower) {
    let divisibleArray = [];
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < myArrayLower.length; i++) {
        if (number % myArrayLower[i].value === 0) {
            divisibleArray[count++] = {name: myArrayLower[i].name, value: myArrayLower[i].value};
        }

    }

    return divisibleArray;

}

function findDivisibles(myArrayUpper, myArrayLower) {
    let divisiblesArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < myArrayUpper.length; i++) {
        let divisibleArray = divisibles(myArrayUpper[i].value, myArrayLower);
        divisiblesArray[i] = {
            name: myArrayUpper[i].name, value: myArrayUpper[i].value,
            found: divisibleArray
        };

    }
    return divisiblesArray;
}
```

Here's the call function

```
let resultArray = findDivisibles(myArrayUpper, myArrayLower);
```

Here is my console.log

```
    let resultArray = findDivisibles(myArrayUpper, myArrayLower);
for (let i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
console.log("Name: " + resultArray[i].name + " Value: " + resultArray[i].value + " Found: ");
let tmpArray = resultArray[i].found;
for (let k = 0; k < tmpArray.length; k++) {
    console.log("        Name: " + tmpArray[k].name + " Value: " + tmpArray[k].value);
}
```

}

The desired output will look something like this

```
{
     name: ”Nathan15”,
     value: 15,
     found:[
     { name: “nathan3”, value: 3},
     { name: “nathan15”, value: 15} ]
}
```

This is my output

```
My output looks like this

Name: Nathan586 Value: 2930 Found: 
Name: Nathan587 Value: 2935 Found: 
Name: Nathan588 Value: 2940 Found: 
    Name: nathan1 Value: 3
    Name: nathan2 Value: 6
    Name: nathan4 Value: 12
```

I can add the rest of the question, code I wrote for previous parts of this question if it helps

Comment: Could you create an example so I can see how it works?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Added my output that I'm getting in the question

Comment: @SithLord Your output seems correct. Do you just want to combine them into a single function?

Comment: If you define how your input arrays look like for `let resultArray = findDivisibles(myArrayUpper, myArrayLower);` it would help